# How would I find the original message from a replied email in PHP imap

Tags: php, imap

I currently can get the `in_reply_to` which gets the `message_id` that was directly replied to, however I want original message.

ex. `4->in_reply_to-->3->in_reply_to-->2->in_reply_to-->1` 
the actual ids look something like this `7336D5A42F8DF66C84D05DSC5D82FDZF39C6D6AB@S04-MBX04-02.s01.local`

In this case I would want 1 as is was the first message sent.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: If all mailers in the transaction support it correctly (mobile clients sometimes don't), the References header's first item should be the 'originator' of the conversation.  If they don't, you would have to follow the chain.  Keeping a local mapping of Message-ID to In-Reply-To, UID should allow you to thread all the messages at once.

Comment: @Max is there a way to find a message by message id?

Comment: Sometimes.  SEARCH HEADER Message-Id message-id; this should work with most servers.  If you're doing them all messages simultaneously, just download all he message-id headers and do it locally.